# Laravel foreach in blade template overiding variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Rather strange bug.

On my user pages, I pass through user data.

```
{{ $user->username }}
```

This will pass through the correct username.

However, if I do something like this:

```
{{ $user->username }}   

@if ($followers->count())
    <h2>Following</h2>
    @foreach ($followers as $user)
        @include('user/partials/userblock')
    @endforeach
@endif

{{ $user->username }}
```

the first $user->username will output correctly, but last one will actually return the last user that was looped in the foreach!

Why is this happening?

Here is the user controller, for those wondering:

```
public function getUser($username) {
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();        

    if (!$user) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'User not found.' );
    }       

    $followers = $user->followers();

    return view('user.index')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('followers', $followers);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another variable:

```
@foreach ($followers as $follower)
    @include('user/partials/userblock', ['user' => $follower])
```

Comment: It works. But, for future reference, why is this happening?

Comment: This is happening because foreach is overriding `$user` variable with other value in each iteration. `foreach` doesn't have it's own scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another variable, something like this:

```
public function getUser($username) {
$cuser = User::where('username', $username)->first();        

if (!$cuser) {
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'User not found.' );
}       

$followers = $cuser->followers();

return view('user.index')
    ->with('cuser', $cuser)
    ->with('followers', $followers);    
}
```

And you blade:

```
{{ $cuser->username }}   

@if ($followers->count())
    <h2>Following</h2>
    @foreach ($followers as $user)
        @include('user/partials/userblock')
    @endforeach
@endif

{{ $cuser->username }}
```

Hope this works!